# How to point a domain name to a sub-directory within your site and have it so that it looks as if it is a separate entity?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I don't know much about htaccess which is why I've had to ask this question and apologies if there is an exact duplicate because I haven't seen one.

I have my domain `abcdefg.co.uk` and I bought another domain name `123456.info` and pointed it to the same name servers for my existing hosting.

On my hosting account cpanel I created a new addon domain for `123456.info` which created a subdirectory in my public_html directory.

So, when I try and navigate to `123456.info` in my browser it takes me to `abcdefg.co.uk/123456.info` is there a way to rewrite or set it up differently so that it just appears as if it is a standalone site?

Thanks for your help

(htaccess file is empty at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: you can change root directory, so there will be no need to rewrite!!!

but if you see it easier , here it is:

```
RewriteRule ^123456.info(.*)$    $1 [L]
```